# How do i write the integers that in this file to the mynumbers.txt file?

Tags: python

Ok this function works perfectly, I just need to know how do i make it so it so the random integers that are generated, are written to the mynumbers.txt file.

```
def main():

#Open a file for writing
 outfile = open ('mynumbers.txt' , 'w')


#Generate random integer number
from random import randint
number = randint(6, 12)
print("Write will create", number, "random numbers")

import random

i = 0
while i < 11:
# Get random number in range 10 through 20.
n = random.randint(10, 20)
print(n)
i += 1
#Write the numbers to the file

foo = ""
while (i):
#find n
foo += str(n) + " "
outFile.write(foo)

#Call the main function
main()
```

Is this right?

Comment: Can you indent your code correctly ? This function cannot work at all like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening the file with the append option instead: `outfile=Open("[FileName]", "a")` Then you can do a `outfile.write(str(n) + " ")` where n is the number you wish to write. Of course you can pick a deliminator other than " ".

Alternatively, you could store all of the numbers in a string. And write them all at the end.

```
foo = ""
while (looping):
    #find n
    foo += str(n) + " "
outFile.write(foo)
```

===REVISED===

```
import random

output = ""
deliminator = "\n" #Put a line-break after each number
filepath = "mynumbers.txt"
i = 0
while i < 11:
# Get random number in range 10 through 20.
    n = random.randint(10, 20)
    print(n) #is this necessary?
    i += 1
    output += str(n) + deliminator

#Write the numbers to the file
with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
    file.write(output)
```

Comment: Oh ok  so I used that. the part that says     (filepath="new.txt") is that still going to write it to the path 'my.numbers.txt' or is it going to the filepath 'new.txt'? @Mortuus

Comment: No problem, glad I could help